# is there a way to include a blade template instead of plain html using phpwkhtmltopdf?

Tags: php, laravel, phpwkhtmltopdf

I am using `phpwkhtmltopdf` package to convert my html to PDF.
how can i convert .blade.php to pdf?

i tried this

```
$pdf = new Pdf;
$pdf->addPage('temp');
$pdf->saveAs('test2.pdf');
```

but it does't work and give me the following error :

QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
    QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
    Error: Failed loading page http:///var/www/html/project/views/temp (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
    Exit with code 1 due to network error: HostNotFoundError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the solution , you can just use View() , like this

```
$pdf->addPage(View('temp'));
```

or

```
$view= view('temp')->render();
$pdf->addPage($view);
```